# How to integrate twilio sms verification into my Node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, twilio

As I am integrating Twilio into my website. It is first of all not working. My code is this

[image]

and app crashes. my userController where I am implementing the code is here

[image]

I am not getting what I want. This is what I am getting on my front UI

[image]

Comment: Please don't add code as screenshots but use the markdown feature.

Answer (score 0):

You see the error because you didn't supply a `to` parameter. This probably happens when the first function argument of `sendSms()` is `null` or `undefined`.

You call `sendSms(User.newphone)` which is probably the mistake as you call the property of what I assume is a class but instead you should try `sendSms(user.newphone)` or `sendSms(newphone)`.

Tip: Don't use the same variable name to avoid this in the future.